# Какой жизненный цикл у компонентов MVP?

Tags: архитектура, mvp, activity-life-cycle

Понятно, что `View` живет, пока живет `Activity` или `Fragment`. А дальше начинаются догадки: `Model` ,по идее, должен жить пока живет само приложение(ведь содержит бизнес-логику), `Presenter` - непонятно...
С учетом, что экземпляров и `Presenter`, и `View` может быть много(а может быть несколько `Model`?(точнее,это может решить какую-то архитектурную проблему?)),то их создание регулирует `Model` и вообще `Model` самый главный?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[вот тут все подробно расписанно](https://habr.com/post/252903/)